# Converting Fractional Coordinates to Cartesian

Tags: matrices

I'm confused about what I am reading online - different sites tell me different answers. Lets say I have a point pair in fractional coordinates, [xf,yf,zf]. I know that to convert them to their Cartesian counterparts, [x,y,z], I multiply by a conversion matrix. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_coordinates#Conversion_to_cartesian_coordinates) has one description of the matrix in which to do this. [This website](http://www.ruppweb.org/Xray/tutorial/Coordinate%20system%20transformation.htm) has a different matrix. The difference between the two lies in row 3 column 3 - one divides by ab and the other multiplies by c.

Which one is correct? Or maybe it's just flying over my head and they are both correct, but for different cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two pages have different definitions of $v$ (or $V$) as well; the ruppweb one has factors of $abc$ that the wikipedia one doesn't. So $\frac{V}{ab}$ in the ruppweb scheme equals $vc$ in the wikipedia scheme, and the two matrices are actually the same.